# CSS won't work when sending HTML email with wp_mail()

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, email

I am trying to send a HTML mail with the Wordpress function wp_mail() like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ) { return 'text/html'; });
$headers = 'From: '. $current_user->user_firstname . ' ' . $current_user->user_lastname .' <'. $current_user->user_email .'>' . "\r\n";
wp_mail( $_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['mail_text'], $headers);
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
```

All HTML tags like `<strong>`, `<li>`, `<p>` etc. come with HTML format. But when I try to change the color using HTML or CSS like `<li style="color:red">Word</li>` or `<li color="red">Word</li>` it won't work and appears as blank text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The text/message you send is in `$_POST['mail_text']` coming from a textarea, right?
Did you echo out the content of `$_POST['mail_text']`? Is it ok before sending?

Try single quotes:

```
<li style='color:#f90'>Hello World</li>
```

and check if somewhere a script calls `strip_tags` to remove html tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Higuest)\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
    $headers .= "Importance: High\n";

    $headers .= "From: Approprice <".$mailfrom.">" . "\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: Approprice <".$mailfrom.">" . "\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: Approprice <".$mailfrom.">";
```

user this headers in email for sending html